# Replace default price template in product view

Tags: magento-1.7, price, blocks, product-view

I'd change the default `catalog/product/price.phtml`

I've tried already:

```
<reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
     <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/custom-price.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

but using `xdebug` I've seen that the `addPriceBlockType` method is not used for the `simple` product, so it returns the default template.

where I'm wrong?
thank you

Comment: Can you not copy the price template in to your own theme? It will look there first.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear, the template should be replace just for a custom handle product type

Answer (score 2):

My actual solution is to rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple`

```
class Store_Core_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Simple extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple{
    protected $_priceBlockDefaultTemplate = 'catalog/product/custom-price.phtml';

    protected function _getPriceBlockTemplate($productTypeId)
    {
        if (isset($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId])) {
            if ($this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'] != '') {
                return $this->_priceBlockTypes[$productTypeId]['template'];
            }
        }
        return $this->_priceBlockDefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

I can now use some logic to choose the correct price template based on product type.
However, I'm wondering if there is any other solution just using xml layouts